# How to manually control which Thread enters critical region using Java Swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to create a simple Java Swing-based application that manually controls two threads which are both trying to continually increment an integer value. The application should be able to **'Start'** and **'Stop'** either of the threads (both threads incrementing the value simultaneously) and put either of the threads in the critical region (only one thread allowed to increment value).

Here's a screenshot of what I have, so that you may better understand what I am aiming for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKhS9.png

I've created an "Incrementor" class which does the job of incrementing the int value, but if I try adding the synchronized keyword to the increment() method, I do not get the result I want.

```
    private void increment() {
        while (Thread.currentThread().isAlive()) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread 1")) {
                if (t1Stop.isEnabled()) {
                    value++;
                    t1TextField.setText("Thread 1 has incremented value by 1. Current value = " + value + "\n");
                }
            } else if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread 2")) {
                if (t2Stop.isEnabled()) {
                    value++;
                    t2TextField.setText("Thread 2 has incremented value by 1. Current value = " + value + "\n");
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any advice on how to proceed?

I hope I've made it clear what it is I am looking for, if not, let me know and I'll update this post.

Comment: See `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` and friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is the dreaded thread lock !!

> but if I try adding the synchronized keyword to the increment() method, I do not get the result I want.

of course ! Thread manager changes the "Working"  thread whenever he feels like it !, and you should post more code here , but from the first look , you are running the same method in both threads , so it will be dropped down to 2 case :-

1. the good case ! 
   the Thread Manager changes the thread after it finishes calling the increment method(good old win win for both threads ^-^).
2. the bad case (and this is what you have faced)
   imagine that a thread accessed the method and before completing the method the thread managers changes it and when the other method tries to access it find's a big nasty `synchronized` in it's face with the lock in the other thread !from here is their is no guarantee what will happen but i can assure you that 90% of this cases result's only pleases the thread manager .

> The application should be able to 'Start' and 'Stop' either of the threads (both threads incrementing the value simultaneously) and put either of the threads in the critical region (only one thread allowed to increment value).

sorry to break it to you but the thread manager is not-controllable my friend .
but we can suggest a fair amount of thing's to the thread manager , so what you are trying to achieve is not possible at the java thread manager .

and stopping thread's ooky dooky , but starting a thread after stopping it is big NO !!!

from the `Thread.start()` documentation

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
>         In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed
>         execution.
>
> throws  IllegalThreadStateException  if the thread was already
>                       started.

here's a very rich link were you can get the topic explained more widely [at the oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use object-level lock using `synchronized` keyword.

=> *Object-level lock* : `To synchronize a non static method or block so that it can be accessed by only one thread at a time for that instance. It is used to protect non static data.`

Example :

```
public class ClasswithCriticalSections {
    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public synchronized int increment() {
      count.incrementAndGet();
      return count;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class ClasswithCriticalSections {
    Object lock1 = new Object();
    Object lock2 = new Object(); 
    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public int increment() {
      synchronized(lock1) {
         count.incrementAndGet();
         return count;
      }
    }
    public int decrement() {
      synchronized(lock2) {
         count.addAndGet(-1);
         return count;
      }
    }
}
```